# Eevee render lighting causes to flicker and distorted

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I'm fairly new to blender with 2.83.  I have the shirt and waist objects using point light as an only source for lighting.  I set up shading nodes using diffuse shader in order to light up the object however it cause to mess up the placement of the shading materials.

Whether I move around the viewport or the point light, my material object causes to flicker and blurs out.

[image]

When I render, it gave me the exact same result as the render preview.  Only the material previews works when  I rendered it from the viewport giving me the correct result however I don't think this would be suitable to finalize my rendering.

Here's a shot of my shading node that I use.

[image]

If I turned off a light, it goes back to normal. The edges or lines of the gradient looks solid and  align perfectly.
[image]

Turning light on somehow causes issues for diffuse shader.  There is  even like overlapping lighting which I dunno  what causes  it.

If I hide a shirt leaving waist and lighting visible, it removes the problem.

[image]

If I hid the waist, leaving a shirt and point light on, the problem still occurs.

[image]

I tried playing around the blend mode and shadow mode but it made the problem worse or nothing have changed.   Also went to the render property to play around the  sampling both render and viewport however it doesn't help.

Right now I'm stuck so I have nowhere else to look for.

Comment: Try turning off soft shadows under `Render Properties > Shadow`

Comment: @Christopher Bennett   Thank you, it works =)